# Addons for standalone heroku postgres database

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

Is it possible to attach addons to a standalone postgres database created at https://postgres.heroku.com ? I'm using the `dev` plan.

The database details page @ https://postgres.heroku.com/databases/ shows ***"Heroku PG-Backups addon not attached"*** under **Snapshots** heading. I couldn't find a way to add the *PG-Backups* addon.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to take a look at the docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups#provisioning-the-add-on

Comment: Since this is a standalone database that is not attached to any app, Heroku CLI tools can't be used against it. So no luck that way :(

Comment: `pg_dump` / `pg_restore` ?

Comment: Probably. If I recall, you can do something like `heroku envs` to get all the environment variables. One of them will point to the URL where the database is hosted.